# dot product of a tuple in python

Tags: python, dot-product

I understand that dot product can be found in the following way:

```
>>> vector1 = (2,3,5)
>>> vector2 = (3,4,6)
>>> sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector1, vector2))
48
```

But I am trying to find the dot product for a tuple say:

```
>>> vector3 = ((2,2),(3,3),(5,5))
>>> vector4 = ((3,3),(4,4),(6,6))
```

How to do this without using numpy.

Can't I just use some statement like `sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector3, vector4))` ?

Because when I tried the same, I got an error as follows:

```
>>> vector3 = ((2,2),(3,3),(5,5))
>>> vector4 = ((3,3),(4,4),(6,6))
>>> sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector3, vector4))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector1, vector2))
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <genexpr>
    sum(p*q for p,q in zip(vector3, vector4))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
>>>
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: @gnibbler  I am sure you would know this

Comment: The pairs you're multiplying are e.g. `(2, 2) * (3, 3)`; what answer did you expect?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I understood that. But I am looking for 2-D array matrix as in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: You need to be more specific what 2D matrix you are looking for. For example are you looking for `np.dot(vector3, np.transpose(vector4))` or `np.dot(np.transpose(vector3), vector4)`, or something else?

Comment: @unutbu Something like the one in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html if you search for "For 2-D arrays it’s the matrix product:"

Comment: For asymmetrical arrays (for instance the 3x2 arrays you gave above) there are two distinct matrix products you could take. Those are the two unutbu was referencing. Without some idea of why you're trying to calculate a matrix product it's impossible to guess which product you actually want to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're considering `vector3` and `vector4` to essentially be lists of vectors, you could do:

```
(sum(p * q for p, q in zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(vector3, vector4))
```

If you want a list of dot product values, you can force evaluation of the above generator object into a list or use a list comprehension instead:

```
# Evaluate into list
list(sum(p * q for p, q in zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(vector3, vector4))

# List comprehension
[sum(p * q for p, q in zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(vector3, vector4)]
```

You're getting that error because you're trying to apply the `*` operator to two tuples which is not defined.

Comment: It gave me an error <generator object <genexpr> at 0x877020c>

Comment: @AnakataAndrese That's not an error.  That's a string representation of the return value.  If you want to see it as a list, use the built-in `list` function...`list(sum(p * q for p, q in zip(a, b)...vector4))`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here is that what you're trying to do is not mathematically well-defined. How would you expect this to work? What should the right output be?

Your `vector3` and `vector4` are really matrices of form `2 by 3`. These are not coordinate vectors. You can't apply a dot product to them. You can apply the dot product operation to `vector1` and `vector2` because they are of form `1 by n`: they are column vectors. You can't apply the dot product to anything that isn't a column vector.